# What is the input type of this data?

Tags: input

What language/notation this is? It looks like JSON, but with the colon in the wrong place.

```
[{:count 0 :value "true"},
{:count 1 :value "false"},
{:count 2 :value "true"}]
```

Comment: Where did you find that? It kind of looks like a Ruby hash using symbols, but it's missing some important parts (namely `=>` and `,`).

Comment: And as you note "the colon is in the wrong place", but more interesting to me is the lack of field delimiters (`,`), since several languages use a prefix `:` for various things.

Comment: I agree. If it helps, there is also a mention of an association list with no delimiters ex: [[9,7] [6,3] [4,2]]